# Choosing the Best Combination of Values from Data frame R

Tags: r

I have a data frame with 20 rows and 10 columns. Each value in the data is a number between 0 and 10.

I want to pick the combination of values with the highest sum, and I have to pick one and only one value from each column.

Is there a ready r function that does this, or a implication of a known algorithm.

Is there an r function that generates all the possible combinations from which I would pick the one with the highest sum?

Comment: Wouldn't you just take the max of each column and then take the sum? i.e. something like `sum(sapply(mydataframe, max))`. Or is this simple problem a proxy for a more complicated problem that can't be decomposed into independent sub-problems?

Comment: When you say combination of values, what exactly do you mean?

Comment: Also, you definitely don't want to generate every combination of values from 10 sets of 20. That would be 20^10 combinations, which is 10,240,000,000,000 combinations.

Comment: combinations of values = picking 10 values out of the data frame. you have to pick one value from each column and each of these values has to be from a different row, therefore a combination of maxes won't necessarily give you the highest possible sum

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're trying to do?  (I'm assuming your data frame is named `df`.)

```
maxList <- c(which(df$col1 == max(df[, 1]))) #Initialize list of row numbers with max value
total <- max(df[, 1])  #Initialize sum of allowable maximum values
combination <- c(total)  #Initialize list of those maximum values

for(i in 2:ncol(df)) {  #For the remaining columns in df
  subCol <- df[, i]
  for(j in 1:length(maxList)) {  #For the number of items in maxList
    subCol[maxList[j]] <- 0  #Set row values of previous maxima to zero
    maxList <- c(maxList, which(subCol == max(subCol)))  #Update maxList
  }
  combination <- c(combination, max(subCol))
  total <- total + max(subCol)  #Update total
}
```

Comment: not really. 
Theoretically the solutions doesn't necessarily needs to include max values of certain columns.

Comment: Think of it as graph with 200 nodes that each of them has a certain weight and limited connectivity to other nodes and you need to find the path in which you go through the nodes that their weight sum is the biggest

Comment: @Eyal  Ok, I hadn't considered that.  I wonder if you executed this code once for each of the 3.6M permutations of column order, and then identified the result(s) that yielded the largest sum, if that would provide a solution, albeit an inelegant one.  (Unfortunately, I don't know how to mathematically prove this.)